# Is it correct to write 0 ≤ 1? or can it be written as 0 < 1 only?

Tags: inequality

Is it correct to write 0 ≤ 1? or can it be written as 0 < 1 only?

I know ≤ means less than **OR** equal to, but I am really confused here.

Comment: It is fine to say that $0 \le 1$, because it is either less than $1$ or equal to $1$.

Comment: We have $0=0$ and $0<1$, _and_ $0\le0$ and $0\le1$. Also, we do _not_ have $1<0$ and we do _not_ have $1=0$, which means that we do _not_ have $1\le0$.

Answer (score 2):

In mathematics "or" is inclusive. It's not like a restaurant where you can order fish or steak but not both. Here you can have the fish, the steak or both of them.

In particular, if $0<1$ is true, then $0<1\text{ or }0=1$ is also true, so $0\leq 1$ is fine.

Comment: Why is inclusive/exclusive or relevant here? "Less than or equal to" means the same thing regardless of which "or" is meant, since you can't have both.

Comment: Akiva, because it seems to be the source of the confusion, and because in other contexts it might matter.